# C printing float arrays into columns

Tags: c, loops, multiple-columns, modulus, output-formatting

I'm trying to print out an array of 100 lf values into columns of ten. I was planning on inserting a new line whenever I hit the tenth data value in each line, but I'm having trouble with my if statement. "Left operand must be 1-value" is the error I keep running into.
Here's the code as is:

```
for (x=0; x<100; x++)
    {
    if (x % 10 = 0)
        {
        printf("\n");
        }
    printf("|%-6.2lf|", i[x]);  
    }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
if (x % 10 = 0)
```

That should be the double-equals sign:

```
if (x % 10 == 0)
```

A common typo.

Comment: A practice that might help mitigate this is putting the literal on the left side, changing `x%10 == 0` to `0 == x%20` can provide this sort of mistake at compile time.